# How to do add element to nested list with transformation?

Tags: xml, list, xslt

Suppose we have such nested list in XML:

```
<section name="SomeSection">
    <!-- list property -->
    <property length="2" name="ExternalList">
        <!-- first element of external list -->
        <listItem name="ExtElement1">
            <property length="3" name="InternalList1">
                <listItem name="SomeElement1" />
                <listItem name="SomeElement2" />
                <listItem name="SomeElement3" />
            </property>
        </listItem>
        <!-- second element of external list -->
        <listItem name="ExtElement2">
            <property length="2" name="InternalList1">
                <listItem name="SomeElement1" />
                <listItem name="SomeElement2" />
            </property>
        </listItem>
    </property>
</section>
```

And we have some new item e.g.:

```
<listItem name="SomeElement3" />
```

What transformation adds a 'SomeElement3' to 'InternalList1' at 'ExtElement2', and also
increases the 'length' attribute of 'InternalList1'?

Thanks.

Comment: There is obviously a typo that makes this question a nonsense: "ExtElement2" is not a descendent of "InternalList1" -- it is its "uncle". You probably meant: add a 'SomeElement3' to 'ExternalList' at 'ExtElement2', and also increase the 'length' attribute of 'ExternalList'

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple, short and easy solution that uses one of the most fundamental XSLT design patterns -- the overriding of the identity rule/template. Absolutely *no* conditional instructions are used!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple stylesheet that takes the details of the new element as parameters:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="extElement" select="'ExtElement2'" />
  <xsl:param name="intElement" select="'SomeElement3'" />

  <xsl:template match="property[@name='ExternalList']/listItem">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@name = $extElement">
        <listItem name="{$extElement}">
          <property length="{property/@length+1}" name="{property/@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="property/listItem" />
            <listItem name="{$intElement}" />
          </property>
        </listItem>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you want to hardcode it into the stylesheet, you can do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="listItem[@name='ExtElement2']/property">
    <property length="{@length + 1}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name() != 'length'] | node()"/>
      <listItem name="SomeElement3" />
    </property>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But you need to specify where you want it to go in the match attribute of the template.

Answer (score 1):

**This short and simple transformation uses and overrides the identity rule**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "property[@name='ExternalList']
     /listItem[@name='ExtElement2']
       /property[@name='InternalList1']
 ">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
   <xsl:attribute name="length">
    <xsl:value-of select="@length+1"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
   <listItem name="SomeElement3" />
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<section name="SomeSection">
    <!-- list property -->
    <property length="2" name="ExternalList">
        <!-- first element of external list -->
        <listItem name="ExtElement1">
            <property length="3" name="InternalList1">
                <listItem name="SomeElement1" />
                <listItem name="SomeElement2" />
                <listItem name="SomeElement3" />
            </property></listItem>
        <!-- second element of external list -->
        <listItem name="ExtElement2">
            <property length="2" name="InternalList1">
                <listItem name="SomeElement1" />
                <listItem name="SomeElement2" />
            </property></listItem>
    </property>
</section>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<section name="SomeSection"><!-- list property -->
   <property length="2" name="ExternalList"><!-- first element of external list -->
      <listItem name="ExtElement1">
         <property length="3" name="InternalList1">
            <listItem name="SomeElement1"/>
            <listItem name="SomeElement2"/>
            <listItem name="SomeElement3"/>
         </property>
      </listItem><!-- second element of external list -->
      <listItem name="ExtElement2">
         <property length="3" name="InternalList1">
            <listItem name="SomeElement1"/>
            <listItem name="SomeElement2"/>
            <listItem name="SomeElement3"/>
         </property>
      </listItem>
   </property>
</section>
```

**Do note:** Absolutely no conditional XSLT instructions are used anywhere in this solution -- they are not necessary at all.

Comment: This is more or less exactly the same as my 2nd solution. I was trying to get my first one to be conditionless as well, the only reason it's not is that the `match` attribute of the template would need to be `property[@name='ExternalList']/listItem[@name=$extElement]`, and the entire body of the template would be what's currently in the `<xsl:when>` block, but XSLT1 doesn't allow variables/params in a template match attribute.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Agreed. But in your second transformation you unnecessaryly hardcode the neme of the "name" attribute. This is why we need to encourage people to use XSLT 2.0.

Comment: True, but it seemed adequate in this case. However, I've updated it.